# Cant add core extension Autodesk.InViewerSearch by step-by-step tutorial Autodesk Forge Viewer v2

Tags: autodesk-forge, autodesk-viewer

I am trying learn Autodesk Forge and its apis. And at one step in  step-by-step viewer v2 (Search in Default UI) i cant add core extension Autodesk.InViewerSearch. My code is  here :

https://gist.github.com/kshyshki/daeda5f64f7f4119da7af8e176c0a103

In result i get in console such error:

```
viewer3D.js:137377 Uncaught (in promise) Extension not found: Autodesk.InViewerSearch. Has it been registered(1)?
```

Help me please i am realy disappointed what i do wrong :(

Comment: See [ask]. Your [mcve] should be included as part of the question, not as a link.

Comment: Thank you. I try, but cant make post if try insert code in post, form was with exclamation mark and with comment like "Your post have more code that your comment", I could not find a better solution that insert code like link on gist github.

Comment: That's because we want you to carefully explain your problem, describe what you did, and then tell us what results you got.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

InViewerSearch extension got removed starting Version 5. Your best way to learn the use of the API would be to follow this tutorial.

http://learnforge.autodesk.io/#/

From the viewer you have access to all the metadata so a search could be recreated on your side. Apologies for the misleading material we are doing cleanup on this.

Comment: Thank you. Before i think if i use v2 in `` <script src="https://developer.api.autodesk.com/modelderivative/v2/viewers/viewer3D.min.js"></script>`` it will have all that have v2 version. Now i understand that i only must use last version. Thank you for link